# How to add list with sections and header inside navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-listview

How to add list with sections and header inside navigation drawer? It tried like following structure.

```
<LinearLayout>

   <TextView>Add Topics</TextView>

   <TextView>Recent Topics</TextView>

   <ListFragment>Recent Topics list items<ListFragment>

   <TextView>My Topics</TextView>

   <ListFragment>My Topics list items<ListFragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I was not able to produce list structure like Latest youtube Application navigation drawer.

Basically I need following structure inside naviagation drawer.

```
  List Item 1 (on click change fragment in home page of application)

  List Item 2 (Disable on click - It will act as Header)

      Inner List Item 1  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 2  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 3  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 4  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 5  (on click change fragment in home page of application)

   List Item 3 (Disable on click - It will act as Header)

      Inner List Item 1  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 2  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 3  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 4  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
      Inner List Item 5  (on click change fragment in home page of application)
```

How to achieve like this layout?

Comment: do you mean like youtube app ?

Comment: yes sure,I need like that only